# How to send a local file through a REST service?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I am developing a REST web service using WCF and C# (VS 2010). I want to develop an operation like this:

```
doSomethingWithAFile(String filePath)
```

so it would be invoked like this:

```
GET http://my.web.service/endpoint?filePath={filePath}
```

`filePath` is a file path in the client (not in the server). So, when invoked, that operation has to send the file pointed by the path to the server so that the server can do some operations with the data contained in the file.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: As stated in the comment I made, I would set a shared folder in the client, so I send the path and the server reads the file in the folder.

Comment: Check out http://restsharp.org/

Comment: The server will not have access to the file, unless it is a shared folder/file, the server has access to that share and the filePath given is the network path to the file. If you want to send files to your server, rather convert the file to BASE64 and send that in the request

Comment: You will have to use a POST method. See here for a good example: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Upload-files-using-a-REST-13f16af2

Comment: I would like to set a shared folder in the client, so the server has access to it. Following this point of view, I would not have to encode the file to send it, I would only send the path to the file and the server reads it. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Eh... by simply sending the full path string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your server, you will have to have a service with a method that accepts a string input, which you call with the file path from the client application.
You then read/copy/whichever the file from that location, on your server via normal file IO methods.

An example of how to do this you can find below.
The definition of `ServerPleaseFetchThisFile` naturally depends on what kind of webservice this would be, WCF or IIS web service or self made web service.

```
public bool ServerPleaseFetchThisFile(string targetPath)
{
  // targetPath should enter from the client in format of \\Hostname\Path\to\the\file.txt
  return DoSomethingWithAFile(targetPath);
}

private bool DoSomethingWithAFile(string targetFile)
{
  bool success = false;

  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(targetFile))
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException("targetFile", "The supplied target file is not a valid input.");
  }

  if (!File.Exists(targetFile))
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException("targetFile", "The supplied target file is not a valid file location.");
  }

  try
  {
    using (FileStream targetStream = new FileStream(targetFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
      // Do something with targetStream
      success = true;
    }
  }
  catch (SecurityException se)
  {
    throw new Exception("Security Exception!", se);
    // Do something due to indicate Security Exception to the file
    // success = false;
  }
  catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uae)
  {
    throw new Exception("Unathorized Access!", uae);
    // Do something due to indicate Unauthorized Access to the file
    // success = false;
  }

  return success;
}
```